# LibreOffice causing conflicts with OpenOffice when installing with apt

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, libreoffice

I was trying to install kubuntu-desktop, and in counted an error with LibreOffice. I can no longer install packages with apt, and when I try using sudo apt install -f. Anytime I try to do anything with apt I get the error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
kubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.398).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.4.6) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

```
sudo apt install -f
```

returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
11 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/23.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 56.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 349645 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1.8-9803
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/program/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Correct: OpenOffice and LibreOffice packages *conflict*. Both sets of debs cannot be installed at the same time. At least one must instead be some other kind of install: A snap or different package type or compiled from source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenOffice and LibreOffice should not be installed with each other.

They are both forks of the same software and will conflict with each other if you try to install them both on the same system.

Answer (score 1):

Found fix by using

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq \
       libreoffice-writer libreoffice-qt5 libreoffice-kf5 libreoffice-core \
       libreoffice-math python3-uno libreoffice-impress libreoffice-draw \
       libreoffice-calc libreoffice-plasma libreoffice-base-core
```